# Olympiad Graph Problem

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

An undirect graph has $100$ vertices. For every four vertices there are at least two edges between them. And also there is no Hamiltonian path (meaning the path that visits each vertex exactly once). P.T there are two vertices such, that any other vertex is connected to one of the two.

I think considering the longest path is useful. I proved the problem if this path contains less than 99 vertices. But if the path contains exactly 99 vertices I wasn't able to do anything. Please, suggest your ideas.

Comment: Not sure "P.T." is an abbreviation in standard use.  Seems unnecessarily obscure.

Comment: @markvs  Why would that be a counterexample?  If we choose one vertex from each of the two complete subgraphs, then every other vertex must connect to (exactly) one of those.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: @markvs  Note that the disjoint union of *three* complete graphs would be a counterexample except that in that case you could take two vertices from one subgraph and one each from each of the other two and for those $4$ vertices there would be only a single edge connecting any two of them, counter to assumptions.

Comment: @markvs Right...so what?  Yes, the disjoint union of two complete graphs satisfies the assumptions.  And it satisfies the conclusion.  I think I am missing your point.  (N.B.  it is entirely possible, likely even, that I am misreading the entire question.  As far as I can see, you don't need the assumption that there are $100$ vertices, nor the assumption that there is no Hamiltonian path).

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: It looks like not the most advanced olympiad. If the graph with the given condition is connected and has at least 5 vertices, then it has a Hamiltonian path. If it is not connected, then it has exactly two components, each of which is a complete graph.

Comment: @kabenyuk we may also have an isolated vertex plus a component that is a clique minus a matching.

Comment: @Guyslain: Yes, you're right. In the unconnected case, there are two possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

So we know that there must be some path containing all but one vertex, call the vertices on such a path $P = v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{n-1}$, and let $u$ be the last vertex. I suggest going on like this.

Consider first the case when $v_1v_{n-1} \in E$, you should be able to check that $E[\{u\}, V(P)] = \emptyset$. Then suppose that $vw \notin E$ for distinct $v,w \in V(P)$. Prove that $v$ and $w$ cover every vertex. Otherwise $V(P)$ is a clique and we are done.

It remains to study the case when $v_1v_{n-1} \notin E$. Check that for $x \in \{v_2,\ldots,v_{n-2}\}$, if $ux \notin E$, then $sx,xt \in E$. From this, $E[\{u\},V(P)] = \emptyset$, we get that $s$ and $t$ cover every vertex. So we may assume there is some $v_i$ with $2 \leq i \leq n-2$ with $uv_i \in E$. Take $i$ minimum and proceed in two cases, whether $i=2$ or not.

There are many details to check, but none is harder than the proof that you can assume that there is a path of length 99.